# Generar un archivo que almacene los matches que coicidan con la Expresion Regular de un archivo de lectura

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: **introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí**]
Quiero almacenar los datos que hicieron match con la expresion regular, quiero que estos datos se almacenen y generen un nuevo archivo con el nombre del archivo que se leyó y todos estos direccionar los a una carpeta

```
import re

pattern1 = re.compile(r"(\w+:\w+\s?= status)|(\w{7,}\s?= status)")

with open("C:\Curso Python\YTS\s.YT3792B","r") as f:            
    leer = f.read()
    matches = pattern1.finditer(leer)


for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

Comment: Hola David, bienvenido a [es.so]. Te recomiendo pasarte por [tour] y [ask] para conocer mejor el sitio y cómo realizar buenas preguntas. Falta información para poder darte una respuesta adecuada, ¿qué datos quieres almacenar?¿cada coincidencia?¿su posición?¿todo?¿el propio objeto re.Match vía Pickle? Por otro lado, ¿qué nombre debe tener el fichero de salida?¿Dependería del nombre del fichero de entrada? ¿En qué ruta debe almacenarse?¿Qué estructura deben tener los datos almacenados en el mismo? Agregar un fichero ejemplo de entrada y la salida esperada ayudarían mucho. Un saludo.

Comment: Saludos, gracias por la recomendación, formulare mejor la pregunta

Comment: Quiero almacenar los datos que hicieron match con la expresion regular, quiero que estos datos se almacenen y generen un nuevo archivo con el nombre del archivo que se leyó y todos estos direccionar los a una carpeta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías hacer algo como:

```
MyFile=open("nombredelarchivo.txt", 'w')
MyFile=write(X)
```

En X tendrías que escribir lo que sea que quieras intorducir en el archivo. En este caso supongo que lo que quieres escribir es lo que está en 'matches'. Recuerda que al final tendrás que cerrar el archivo (`MyFile.close()`).

Comment: Muchisimas gracias lo intentare de esta manera